# Why does git rebase --onto a b, git rebase --onto b a create a different SHA1 from the original?

Tags: git

Suppose you have the following revision graph, with c as the current branch:

```
c   a
 \ /
  b
```

`git rebase --onto a b` creates the following:

```
    c
   /
  a
 /
b
```

and `git rebase --onto b a` returns the graph to:

```
c   a
 \ /
  b
```

However, the new SHA1 of c is different from the old SHA1 of c, before both rebasings. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SHA1 of a commit depends on everything about the commit, including the metadata. In particular, it depends on the commit timestamp. Your twice-rebased commit has a new timestamp, so it has a new SHA1.

(Note that there's an "author date", when it was originally written, and a "commiter date", when the actual commit was recorded. Only the latter has changed. To see this for yourself, use `git log --pretty=fuller`, or just look at the commit in `gitk`.)

Comment: Interesting. What was confusing me was that it was not changing the SHA1 when there were no additional commits past the new base onto which rebasing was being performed. I guess if you have extra work beyond the new base, it requires the creation of new commits, and hence a new timestamp(s).

Comment: @jonderry: I believe rebase is intelligent enough to not do anything if it doesn't have to.

Comment: I wouldn't point out the timestamp so much as the *history*.  A commit has a parent and that's included in the hash.  If the parent changes, the commit changes.  If the parent doesn't change, and nothing else about the commit is changing, there's not necessarily anything to do.

Comment: @Dustin: Look at the question again. The commit was rebased back onto its original parent.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I answered a question that wasn't asked.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Dustin: No worries; it's a question often asked!